# bsxfun vs repmat using different sized matrix inputs to match indices

Tags: matlab, indexing, match, bsxfun

I know there are already a lot of questions regarding how `bsxfun` is supposed to be faster than `repmat`, so I hope this question isn't too redundant.

I am using a short code with repmat. The purpose of this code is to identify indices between `A` and `B` where the row vectors are the same so I can later remove them, but using `repmat` takes far too long using Matlab R2016a.

```
[~,i] = min(abs(dot(A',repmat(B,length(A),1)')./sqrt(sum(A'.^2))./norm(B)-1));
```

Here `A` and `B` are not necessarily the same size, so using `repmat` doesn't seem to work in general anyway. Currently the size of `A` and `B` are 8020x3 and 21615x3. I have found that this method of making the sizes of `A` and `B` the same works but I am open to other methods as well.

```
if isequal(size(A),size(B))==1

else
    a = size(A,1);
    b = size(B,1);

    if a<b
        A = [A;nan(abs(B-A),3)];
    else
        B = [B;nan(abs(B-A),3)];
    end
end
```

I was looking at the `bsxfun` documentation and on this Mathworks site https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/297088-speed-up-indexing-repmat-operation and it seems like I should be able to replace `repmat(B,length(A),1)'` with `bsxfun(@times, B, length(A))` but they do not output the same final array, so I must be doing something incorrect.

If possible I would like to modify my code above so that it takes less time to calculate, and also have `A` and `B` be different sizes such as given above if possible. If necessary, I can still work with `A` and `B` being the same size but they will be both be larger, in this case 571000x3 so the calculations will take longer for this reason as well.

**Addition:**
In the comments, it was discussed whether `intersect` would work. Theoretically, it should since `A` (black) and `B` are defined as being inside or outside the isosurface (red) within a larger volume `T` using the function `inpolyhedron` https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37856-inpolyhedron-are-points-inside-a-triangulated-volume-#comments. For some reason, the output of `inpolyhedron` is a set of the points within the isosurface with some scattered points outside as well. When using `inpolyhedron` to find the values **outside** the isosurface, these "extra" scattered points are not included in the set `B`, so `intersect` finds an empty set when inputting `A` and `B`. [image: Points inside the isosurface]

Comment: Set operators (`setdiff`, `intersect`, `unique`, etc.) all can operate on rows. You are looking for `intersect` I believe.

Comment: Unfortunately, intersect doesn't output indices, but it might still work. It also seems to output one column vector.

Comment: Yes, it does. It outputs indices as 2nd and 3rd output arguments, and can treat rows as units, with the 'rows' option.

Comment: Yes I tried that and you are correct about the indices. However I was not able to use the rows option without error.

Comment: My mistake, I was trying something else with rows, not intersect, which gave errors. Unfortunately, with my data intersect doesn't work, I think it has to do with how I am defining A and B.

Comment: If you have floating-point values, equality comparison might not work as expected. One workaround is to round values to a given number of decimal places.

Comment: Won't that find too many points then? I'm working with position data, so it needs to be exact.

Comment: Also A and B are made from a pre-existing Nx3 array, let's call it T, so A and B are both subsets of T but A and B don't necessarily intersect, although for my purposes they should theoretically.

Comment: You need to pick the distance that you assume equivalent. If your distances are in kilometers, then a millimeter would be a meaningless distance, you can consider those points equivalent. So you round your values to 10 millimeter precision. This is just to get the numerical imprecision in your values to not interfere with equality comparison.

Comment: On the other hand, if they contain exact equivalent numbers because you copied the same values into two arrays, `intersect` should just work.

Comment: Exactly, the only reason why I think I'm having any trouble at all using `intersect` is because `A` and `B` are premade without intersecting unintentionally. But since I'm using someone else's code to make `A` and `B` called `inpolyhedron` I have no easy way figure out the problem. If it would help, I can make two screenshots showing the problem with intersect that I'm having and update the question when I get to my office in a few minutes.

Comment: Also, all the data in `A` and `B` are normalized.

Comment: It seems to me that the right solution is to find a better solution than `inpolyhedron`. If it is broken, don’t use it. :)

Comment: That is the only tool that seems to get even remotely close to what I need for non-convex shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the creator of `inpolyhedron` has a "patch" that mostly corrects this issue.

Essentially you need to move the points by a small amount.

Let's say all of my points are in an array called `TestPoints`.

```
TestPoints = combvec(x',y',z')';  % x, y, and z are column vectors
NudgedPoints = TestPoints + repmat([1e-10 1e-10 0],length(TestPoints),1);
```

Create a surface with faces and vertices from the data

```
[F,V] = isosurface(X,Y,Z,A,-3);   % you can use any value, and X, Y, and Z are positions from a meshgrid
in = inpolyhedron(F,V,NudgedPoints,'FlipNormals',false);
TestPoints_in = TestPoints(in,:);
```

All credit to this solution goes to Sven the creator of `inpolyhedron`. You can get in touch with him [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37856-inpolyhedron-are-points-inside-a-triangulated-volume#comments).